# Spring portlet ehcache delete cache on portlet undeploy

Tags: portlet, ehcache, spring-portlet-mvc

I am using Spring portlet ehcache in Liferay environment 6.x

problem is in dev environment if i drop portlet war to deploy folder. After 3-4 attempts it gives me perm gen/ out of memory exception.

Is there a way if my portlet getting redeploy or undeploy remove the cache, i know i can delete the cache by calling `getCacheManager().remove("cacheKey");` but when i should to call this any idea how to hook it with portlet instance getting off?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution

```
@PreDestroy
public void cleanup() {

     getCacheManager().removeCache(KEY_SERVICE_CACHE);
     getCacheManager().removeCache(KEY_SOURCE_CACHE);

}
```